# Best score in this puzzle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, graph-theory, algorithms, puzzle

I want to maximise the score of the following table, choosing one item from each column/row, so no two items are on the same row or column. Score to maximise is just adding all the choices together.

$$*\quad A\quad B\quad C\quad D\quad E$$
$$\alpha\quad 16\quad 16\quad 18\quad 18\quad 18$$
$$\beta\quad 20\quad 18\quad 16\quad 12\quad 10$$
$$\gamma\quad 20\quad 18\quad 18\quad 16\quad 16$$
$$\delta\quad 18\quad 18\quad 16\quad 16\quad 8$$
$$\epsilon\quad 10\quad 12\quad 14\quad 14\quad 14$$

Example: ($^{C}$ means chosen)

$$*\quad A\quad B\quad C\quad D\quad E$$
$$\alpha\quad 16^{C}\quad 16\quad 18\quad 18\quad 18$$
$$\beta\quad 20\quad 18\quad 16\quad 12\quad 10^{C}$$
$$\gamma\quad 20\quad 18^{C}\quad 18\quad 16\quad 16$$
$$\delta\quad 18\quad 18\quad 16^{C}\quad 16\quad 8$$
$$\epsilon\quad 10\quad 12\quad 14\quad 14^{C}\quad 14$$

Gives a score of $16+10+18+16+14=74$

Now there are a few ways to do this, but can firstly, someone actually tell me if $88$ really is the best result, and secondly show me how to do it via graph theory. I think I have done it by graph theory matching myself, and will put up my solution as an answer below.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm

Comment: @ErickWong Doesn't that minimise?

Comment: @Statisticslove If you minimize the matrix with negative numbers, it is the same as maximizing...

Comment: @5xum Have you looked at the method? That couldn't possibly work...?

Comment: cs.stackexchange.com would probably give you a lot more expert opinion on this kind of question.

Comment: @DanielV Well it can be solved with Graph theory, which is something I would like to see and I would like other mathematical methods to solve it if possible.

Comment: Wikipedia suggests that rather than negating the entries, you just subtract them from a sufficiently large value (such as the maximum entry), which is certainly no less effective and maintains a positive entry table.

Comment: @DanielV That gives a minimum Daniel?

Comment: Imagine your table is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$.  The maximum entry is $5$.  So if you use the hungarian algorithm to minimize $\begin{bmatrix} 5-1 & 5-2 \\ 5-3 & 5-5 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 3 \\ 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix} \Rightarrow \begin{bmatrix} 4^C & 3 \\ 2 & 0^C \end{bmatrix}$, then then that minimum corresponds to a maximum of $\begin{bmatrix} 1^C & 2 \\ 3 & 5^C \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @DanielV Very nice!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $88$ is the maximum.

First, a score of $88$ can be attained, e.g., by choosing $\alpha E,\beta A,\gamma C,\delta B,\epsilon D$, for a score of $18+20+18+18+14=88$ (I think there are $6$ ways to get a score of $88$ but that's not important.)

To beat $88$, you would need to make at least $90$, since (for some silly reason) all the entries are even numbers. If you were allowed to take the biggest element from each row, you would get $18+20+20+18+14=90$. But you can't do that, because the two $20$s are in the same column. So $88$ is the maximum, like I said.

Alternatively, you could just run through the $5!=120$ possible selections by hand in a few minutes.

Comment: Yeah that was the rough logic I had, I wasn't sure how to make it perfectly rigorous, thank you. Why is even silly ;P?

Comment: Perhaps "contrived" is a more accurate word than "silly".

Comment: @DanielV How so?

Comment: @DanielV I intentionally multiplied all entries by $2$ changed rows and then transposed so I could avoid any punishment for posting an assignment question? I don't think I would bother :P

Comment: There's nothing silly about even numbers. What's silly is to make **all** the numbers in the puzzle even. Why multiply them all by $2$? Why not by $100$? I always thought it was silly that in the game of bridge all scores are multiples of $10$.

Comment: There is only a $1$ in $33,554,432$ chance that they would all randomly be even.  But that makes me wonder what is the value of $$\sum_{p \in \text{ primes }}^{p \to \infty } \left(\frac 1 {p^{25}}\right)$$ or the probability that they are all multiples of a given number.

Comment: @Statisticslove When I copied your matrix down on paper, I divided all the entries by $2$.

Comment: @DanielV I think your sum overestimates the probability, because you are adding probabilities of non-disjoint events.

Comment: @DanielV It says [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RelativelyPrime.html) the probability that **two** integers are relatively prime is $6/\pi^2$.

Comment: @DanielV The probability that $25$ integers have some common factor is $1 - 1/\zeta(25) = 1 - \prod_p (1 - p^{-25})$, but if you think about how quickly the terms $p^{-25}$ drop off, this is almost identical to $2^{-25}$ anyway.